# Do I need to document a change of name in childhood for a simple UK passport renewal?

Tags: passports, uk-citizens, applications

1. When I was a child, my parents changed their surname and so my surname changed with it. I also decided to drop my middle names in ~1994.
2. When I applied for my first passport in 1996, I supplied documentation for my changes of name. (These have since been lost.)
3. I don't recall needing to supply any documents of name changing when I renewed in 2006.
4. I have not changed my name since 1996 when I first held a passport.

Do I need to provide documentation of my name changing to renew now? Section 2 of the form asks for "Maiden or all previous names" but I think that's only applicable for name changes since the previous renewal.

Comment: I would distinguish between putting your old name in the "all previous names" section (which to my reading quite clearly doesn't mean names you had last time you renewed) and fully documenting and proving the change.

Answer (score 4):

I just called the passport office. I don't need to document my childhood name changes but I do need to state my former name on the form.